# .htaccess force SSL with subfolder rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I have an app on my server in the `/app/` folder which I am showing on the root URL `http://myapp.com` with the following .htaccess rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /app/ [L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/app/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/$1 [L]
```

What I want to do is also force SSL for this to always use `https://myapp.com` with this set up.

I've tried a bunch of different rules but nothing seems to force the SSL and also keep the /app/ subfolder showing at the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
RewriteRule ^$ /app/ [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Using this I get an error in Chrome: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: @Ian I have updated the rewrite conditions, try it now

Comment: Unfortunately it's still showing a too many redirects error :/ It might be that my original rules aren't ideal. Really I just want it to force SSL and non-www, show the app folder at the root, and rewrite the css/js file urls that are in /app/ so they appear to be in the root.

Comment: @Ian its because of browser's cache, clear your browser cache or use a diffrent web browser

Comment: I tried incognito, Safari, Firefox - all have too many redirects. Thanks for your help so far though!

Comment: @Ian do you have any other rules?

Comment: Nope, your answer is the entirety of my .htaccess file

Comment: @Ian i tested the code on my server. This works fine.

Comment: It must be a config problem with my server then? I have the code exactly as-is and it gets stuck in a redirect loop. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: @Ian Redirect loop error happens when a Rule with R flag redirects a url to itself. You can see the first rule, it redirects http://example.com to a diffrent destination (http => https) https://example.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110025/discussion-between-ian-and-starkeen).

Comment: @Ian I am sorry, I can't continue the discussion right now, I need to go to the market! I will b back in 2 hours. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my host has their own particular way of doing this. I had to do the following to get it working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
RewriteRule ^ https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ /app/ [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/$1 [L]
```

The only problem now is that I can seem to force the www to redirect to non-www.